# Why am I getting a negative information gain?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree, entropy

[SOLVED]

My mistake was that I did not realise that entropy is 0 if all are of one type. Thus if all are positive, entropy is 0 and if all are negative it is zero as well. Entropy will be 1 if equal amount are positive and negative.

It does not make sense that one would get negative information gain.

However based on this example I am getting a negative information gain.

here is the data:
[image]

And if I calculate the information gain on the Humidity attribute I get this:

[image]

Obviously I am missing something here.

EDIT:
To clarify how I understand it.

Entropy of the whole system is defined as:

[image]

Which in this case then is:

[image]

And the information gain per atribute is defined as:

[image]

Which for humidity I calculate to:

Entropy of system - (1/4)Entropy of Humidity Normal - (3/4)Entropy of Humidity High

As per this Libre Office Calc:
[image]

Or is my understanding of the formula for information gain for an attribute incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, I'm assuming your *S* variable is *EnjoySport*. (I think you could phrase the text more clearly, BTW.)

So the entropy of *S* is 0.8113, but that's the last part with which I agree.

The entropy of *S* given *Normal* is 0, as it is deterministic.

The entropy of *S* given *High* is 0.91829583405448945, but you need to multiply that by 0.75, because that is the probability of *Normal*. So that gives you 0.68872187554086706.

The difference is non-negative, as expected.

---

Note that the Information gain is the [expected difference in Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain_in_decision_trees#Formal_definition), and the expectation needs to take into account the probability of the conditioned event.

Comment: Hi Ami, thanks. I found my mistake. Entropy is 0 if all are negative or all are positive. Entropy is 1 if equal number is positive and negative.

Comment: Right you are, but also don't forget to multiply by the probability of the event on which you're conditioning the variables in the calculation of the information gain! I must say, it's nice to see here a question about entropy.