# Negative value of Information Gain

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, decision-tree, entropy, information-gain

I'm implementing C4.5 and in my calculations im getting (for some examples) negative values for information gain. I read [Why am I getting a negative information gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362320/why-am-i-getting-a-negative-information-gain), but my issiue seeams to be diffrent. I putt my calculation to excel and i get the same results as below:

[My calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUHjb.jpg)

What am i doing wrong?

I tried calculate it again, and also i get negative value as is on image below:
[Newest calculations with data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZByfq.jpg)
80 is split value, so i get 11 <=80 and 3objects > 80

Comment: What is the formula for entropy that you are using?

Comment: Entropy formula: - SUM( probability * LOG( BASE 2, probability))

Answer (score 0):

Are you multiplying your result for entropy by `-1`?

$$ H(X) = -\sum_{i=1}^n {\mathrm{P}(x_i) \log_b \mathrm{P}(x_i)} $$

Ugh... having trouble with mathjax, [go here for definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Definition)

Comment: Yes i'm multiplying entropy by -1, my eg. formula =-(N3*LOG(N3;2)+O3*LOG(O3;2))